# How to make column heads of table be multiline?

Tags: tables

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Practically Used Deep CNN Networks}
\label{table1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
NET WIT DATASET  &  CNN layer  &  in a network  &  combining from 2 networks  &  combining from 3 networks
\\ \hline \\
LeNet   MNIST            &  conv1       &  20       &   15      &   15 \\
LeNet MNIST            &  conv2     &  50       &  59       &   59 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &conv1      &24     &15     &16 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &conv2      &96     &107        &107 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How to make column head be multiline?

Comment: Either use fixed width columns or take a look at the makecell package.

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but please remove the \\ after the hline. This will only lead to a large space between the line and the following row as well as to interrupted vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I define a new command `\thead`, which encloses your headings in nested `tabular`s. You have to manually break the lines. I have also added some font commands, just for illustration of where you have to add commands to affect all part of the heading.

In addition, I suggest you load the package [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array), and add some additional space to the rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt} % Add space to rows

\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\small\bfseries\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Practically Used Deep CNN Networks}
\label{table1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c|c|c|c@{}}
\thead{NET WIT\\DATASET}  &  \thead{CNN\\layer}  &  \thead{in a\\network}  &  \thead{combining\\ from\\2 networks } &  \thead{combining\\from\\3 networks}
\\ \hline
LeNet MNIST             &  conv1 & 20  &  15 &   15 \\
LeNet MNIST             &  conv2 & 50  &  59 &   59 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10         &  conv1 & 24  &  15 &   16 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10         &  conv2 & 96  & 107 &  107 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and allow line breaks in columns 1, 4, and 5.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{AlexNet CIFAR10} % measure width of 1st col.
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Practically Used Deep CNN Networks}
\label{table1}
\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{\mylen}|c|c|C|C @{}}
NET WIT DATASET  &  CNN layer  &  In a network  &  Combining from 2 networks  &  Combining from 3 networks\\ 
\hline 
LeNet MNIST     &conv1   &  20     &  15   &   15 \\
LeNet MNIST     &conv2   &  50     &  59   &   59 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &conv1   &  24     &  15   &   16 \\
AlexNet CIFAR10 &conv2   &  96     & 107   &  107 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```